# how can I access the label of phone number in AddressBook

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am using following code

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(i1, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multi)>0){
    NSString *no= (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    alarmData.no1=no;
}
```

This returns the phone number on particular location,but how can I access the label on that location 
i.e

> home 4564645645646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers using follwing code

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(i1, kABPersonPhoneProperty); 
if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multi)>0){ 
    NSString no= (NSString)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, 0);
    alarmData.no1=no;
}
```

Comment: HI @Ali remember when you post any block of code tap 4 spaces before the lines of code,that will convert simple lines into actual code snippet.